# Simplest Async TextWriter to TextReader stream/pipe

Tags: c#-4.0, iostream, producer-consumer

Does .Net (4.0) have an existing class that would allow one thread to write text and the other read?

Ideally I'd use a MemoryStream like:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(memStream);
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(memStream);

//Consumer Thread
(new Thread(delegate() 
{
   while (true)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadLine());
   }
})).Start();

// Producer thread
(new Thread(delegate() 
{
   while (true)
   {
     Thread.Sleep(1000);       
     tw.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now));
   }
})).Start();
```

This Doesn't work since the streamwriter advances the Position in the stream and the reader won't see anything unless it rewinds with Seek which creates concurrency issues with both reader and writer affecting the Position Pointer.

This can be done pipes or sockets, both of which are overkill.  A RYO code with locks seems equally weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`BlockingCollection<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).  Just add items (text) to the collection from one thread, and use `TryTake` or `GetConsumingEnumerable` from the other.

Answer (score 1):

A `BlockingCollection` will work, but it's a little strange if you want Stream semantics.

Nothing in the Framework. I created what I called a `ProducerConsumerStream` to do it. See [Building a new type of stream](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852).